# Are there any limits on length of string in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using MySQL data base with Rails. I have created a field of type `string`. Are there any limits to its length? What about type `text`?
Also as `text` is variable sized, I believe there would be extra costs associated with using text objects. How important can they get, if at all?

Comment: If someone may be interest in quick answer, the longest text I menage to put into `STRING` (in MySQL 5.5) was 1056 characters long.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

String, in general, should be used for short text. For example, it is a `VARCHAR(255)` under MySQL.

Text uses the larger text from the database, like, in MySQL, the type `TEXT`.

For information on how this works and the internals in MySQL and limits and such, see the other answer by Pekka.

If you are requesting, say, a paragraph, I would use text. If you are requesting a username or email, use string.

Comment: Looks like there is still a limit on type TEXT (655365) viz: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html (see also LONGTEXT as an option)

Answer (score 41):

### CHAR

> A fixed-length string that is always right-padded with spaces to the specified length when stored The range of Length is 1 to 255 characters. Trailing spaces are removed when the value is retrieved. `CHAR` values are sorted and compared in case-insensitive fashion according to the default character set unless the `BINARY` keyword is given.

### VARCHAR

> A variable-length string. Note: Trailing spaces are removed when the value is stored (this differs from the ANSI SQL specification)
>   The range of Length is 1 to 255 characters. `VARCHAR` values are sorted and compared in case-insensitive fashion unless the `BINARY` keyword is given

### TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT

> A `TINYBLOB` or `TINYTEXT` column with a maximum length of 255 (2<sup>8</sup> - 1) characters

### BLOB, TEXT

> A `BLOB` or `TEXT` column with a maximum length of 65,535 (2<sup>16</sup> - 1) characters , bytes = 64 KiB

### MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT

> A `MEDIUMBLOB` or `MEDIUMTEXT` column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (2<sup>24</sup> - 1)characters , bytes = 16 MiB

### LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT

> A `LONGBLOB` or `LONGTEXT` column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 (2<sup>32</sup> - 1) characters , bytes =  4 GiB

See [MySQL Data Types Quick Reference Table](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file) for more info.

also you can see [MYSQL -  String Type Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)

Answer (score 5):

See the mySQL manual on [String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-types.html).

Varchar (String):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

Text: See [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

If you want a fixed size text field, use `CHAR` which can be 255 characters in length maximum. `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` both have variable length.

Comment: This isn't relevant to migrations, which uses "string" and "text"

Comment: @~mathepic there was no mention of Rails in the original question - only mySQL. Thanks for the heads up though.