# What column type does SQLAlchemy use for "Text" on MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My overall use-case is trying to determine whether I can write a somewhat database agnostic (at least supporting Postgres and MySQL) store for some large data as raw text (think ~500MB as a rough theoretical upper bound).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578637/2540669) about MySQL string/text types, it looks like only the `LONGTEXT` column type can meet my requirements. I'm using SQLAlchemy, which claims for its [`Text`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text) column type that it is for variable length strings, but also that it generally maps to the database's `CLOB` or `TEXT` types. MySQL doesn't have a `CLOB` type (though it does have a BLOB), and its `TEXT` type would be insufficient for my needs.

So, *What column type does SQLAlchemy use for `Text` on MySQL?*

Comment: If `TEXT` is not large enough then you may have to use a `BLOB` type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, In MySQL, `TEXT` and `BLOB` both support content 64KB in length. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like SQLAlchemy supports LONGTEXT:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 29 2017, 15:31:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGTEXT
>>>
```

See how to use vendor-specific types here:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#vendor-specific-types

For what it's worth, trying to develop a totally brand-neutral database layer is difficult, and rarely worth the effort. I worked on the Zend Framework 1.0 some years ago, and I tried to create a generic unit testing suite for all the SQL databases supported by that framework. I found that very few data types are supported in the same way across all implementations of SQL, despite them all claiming to support the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Ultimately, you have to develop your own class hierarchy for your data layer, and implement the code slightly differently for each database-specific adapter.

---

Update: I think the news is better than we think. I tried this test:

```
t2 = Table('t2', metadata,
      Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
      Column('t1', String(64000)),
      Column('t2', String(16000000)),
      Column('t3', String(4294000000)),
      Column('t4', Text)
     )

metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Then I checked to see what it ended up creating in the MySQL database:

```
mysql> show create table t2;

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t1` mediumtext,
  `t2` longtext,
  `t3` longtext,
  `t4` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

So it does map SQLAlchemy's generic `String` data type to a more-or-less appropriate MySQL data type.

It's not surprising to me that it used larger data types than we might expect. The `MEDIUMTEXT` supports 16MB in *bytes*, not in *characters*. Because my default character set is the multi-byte utfmb4, the max length of `MEDIUMTEXT` is actually much fewer than 2^24 characters. So it had to upgrade it to `LONGTEXT`. Of course, 2^32 characters won't fit in `LONGTEXT` either, but it appears SQLAlchemy assumes you mean to create a column anyway.

I still think that it's hard to do totally implementation-neutral code. For example, what if you want to use some MySQL features like table options for the storage engine, or specific data types with no generic equivalent (for example, `ENUM`)?

Comment: Thanks! Useful to know, but Postgres does not support LONGTEXT, rather its TEXT type just supports large data. I want to avoid having separate logic for Postgres and MySQL if I can

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Be my guest, but I think you'll come to the same conclusion after a few months of trying.

Comment: I am a little afraid that might be the case! Just in the "exploring options" stage right now, and want to either confirm or refute those fears if I can. The  lure of SQLAlchemy's ability to abstract away most of the vendor nuances is the only reason I have hope it might be doable for our case

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! Just for completeness, would you mind adding one more column like `Column('t4', Text)` (note no length is specified for Text) and showing what that maps to (would do it myself, but don't have easy access to a MySQL DB right now)? With that, I think this qualifies as the answer

Comment: You can also try `Column('t1', sqlalchemy.Text().with_variant(sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.LONGTEXT, "mysql"))`

Answer (score 19):

In SQLAlchemy 1.2.7, the Text data type maps to MySQL Type `TEXT`, or `LONGTEXT` depending on the length you enter.

```
body_html = Column(Text())
body_plain = Column(Text(4294000000))
```

Creates the following in MySQL:

```
| Field           | Type         | 
+-----------------+--------------+
| body_html       | text         |
| body_plain      | longtext     |
```