# Convert data_type of table to MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT from Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql

### The size of MySQL Text type is 64KB

If I want to create a bigger text table, such MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT.

I have tried the method with String('big number'), such as String(1000000), it works only SQLAlchemy, not in **Flask-SQLAlchemy**.

So, is the problem in Flaks-SQLAlchemy? or something wrong?

### Before usage

such as:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Post(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(60))
    body = db.Column(db.Text())
```

### Current Usage and it Works!

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Post(db.Model):
    title = db.Column(db.String(60))
    body = db.Column(db.Text(10000000))
```

The bigger number in Text() will automatily create a big text data type in MySQL. 10000000 will convert to longtext.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this test:

```
t2 = Table('t2', metadata,
      Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
      Column('t1', String(64000)),
      Column('t2', String(16000000)),
      Column('t3', String(4294000000)),
      Column('t4', Text)
     )

metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Then I checked to see what it ended up creating in the MySQL database:

```
mysql> show create table t2;
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t1` mediumtext,
  `t2` longtext,
  `t3` longtext,
  `t4` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

So it does map SQLAlchemy's generic String data type to a more-or-less appropriate MySQL data type.

(The above is copied from my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47644801/20860 from 2017. I haven't done this test since then.)

Comment: Thank you! I know this works on SQLAlchemy. But I use Flask-SQLAlchemy, I have no idea to realize this effect via Flask-SQLAlchemy and pymysql on CentOS server.

Comment: Maybe the problem is pymysql. Because I have no error on the local test.

Comment: Okay I didn't realize Flask-SQLAlchemy was a different implementation. Anyway, the answer above is at least a test case. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! you give me an idea to think more. 64000 > 64KB, so it will be mediumtext. I think is Flask-SQLAlchemy is not supporting that way to convert.

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy *is* SQLAlchemy for the most parts. It does use a custom declarative base and a few other things, but `sqlalchemy.String is db.String` is `True`.

Comment: I try to use Text(100000) or bigger number, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use Text(10000000) to convert it. Luckily, it works!

I look up my MySQL, it well and no error on `pymysql`

```
mysql> SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='post' and COLUMN_NAME = 'body';
+-----------+
| DATA_TYPE |
+-----------+
| text      |
| longtext  |
+-----------+
```

**So, my question is done!**